# Retornar valor em consulta SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-select

Preciso que esta consulta retorne 2 ao invés de A.
TIPOUSUARIO é do tipo varchar.

alguém pode me dizer onde está o erro?

```
    USE DATABASE
    SELECT TIPOUSUARIO 
        FROM TABLE UP (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE 
             TIPOUSUARIO = case TIPOUSUARIO when 'A' THEN '2' END

        GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O case geralmente vem antes do `where` la no `select`.

Sua queria deveria ser assim;

```
USE DATABASE
    SELECT case TIPOUSUARIO when 'A' THEN '2' END
        FROM TABLE UP (NOLOCK) 

        GO
```

Assim funciona ois i case não é uma função comparativa e sim uma função condicional para um determinado valor.

Comment: funcionou dessa forma, Obrigado!

Comment: show , marca como concluído então abraços

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE TIPOUSUARIO 
          WHEN 'A' THEN 2 
          ELSE 9
          END FROM UP
  WHERE ...FILTRO....
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara não sei se o nome do campo funciona no `where` da forma que você esta fazendo, mas, tente colocar o  `WHEN` logo após o `case`.

```
TIPOUSUARIO = case when TIPOUSUARIO = 'A' THEN '2' END.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro maior esta no uso incorreto da [Sintaxe do CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

Não dar para entender muito o que você esta tentando fazer, mas se você quer que o retorno seja 2 no logar do valor que esta no `TIPOUSUARIO`, você pode usar seu `case` no `select` assim.

```
USE DATABASE
SELECT case when TIPOUSUARIO = 'A' THEN '2' END 
    FROM TABLE UP (NOLOCK)        
    GO
```

Agora se você que usar usar o `case` no `where` seria.

```
USE DATABASE
SELECT TIPOUSUARIO
    FROM TABLE UP (NOLOCK)  
     WHERE 
         TIPOUSUARIO = case when TIPOUSUARIO = 'A' THEN '2' END      
    GO
```

isso funcionaria se existir `TIPOUSUARIO = 'A'` e `TIPOUSUARIO = '2'`.